# How do I create the right RegEx pattern to recognize values between "," (or before and after)?

Tags: regex, sap-business-bydesign

I'm having trouble developing the right RegEx pattern to recognize certain codes.
My basis is e.g. "10000, 200, 30000" or "Cod_abc, CO_Abc23, Bla_Bla".

It must be possible to read out the individual values between the comma and store them separately.

I have already tried a few things.
`\w+[^,]+/g` has been the best attempt so far.

I'm just not quite sure if the pattern is right and I have a mistake elsewhere, or if the pattern is simply not right.

I try to get the values ("10000", "200", "...") from the string to process them further.

Programming language : ABSL by SAP.

Comment: why us can not using split?

Comment: Split with a comma, `s.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest regex to match terms that are separated by commas is:

```
[^,]*
```

The greedily matches anything not a comma, and will match empty terms too.